# KafkaJs Publish Multiple Messages Error Handling

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

If one of the messages in the messages array fails to be produced in the Kafka topic then will it also prevent other messages to be produced?

```
const producer = kafka.producer()

await producer.connect()
await producer.send({
    topic: 'topic-name',
    messages: [
        { key: 'key1', value: 'hello world' },
        { key: 'key2', value: 'hey hey!' }
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't prevent other messages from being produced. In particular if the messages go to other partitions/brokers.

For example, imagine 3 brokers and 3 partitions. A producer could send one message to each broker, and maybe one comes back as failed due to a network connection issues. I'm not sure if the JS driver does a internal batching (like the java client), which could also create other situations in which some messages are produced while others fail even if they go to the same partition.

If you need all or nothing semantics, KafkaJS supports [transactions](https://kafka.js.org/docs/transactions).

Comment: I want to produce messages in batches. I will handle error messages which will be failed to publish separately. But I have to ensure that the faulty message never interepet publishing valid messages

Comment: I don't think the driver reports which messages failed. Looking at the code (which is quite unreadable), it looks like on an error it throws an exception without specifying which messages failed. The driver is open-source, so you can contribute to it and add this feature. Otherwise use transactions.

Comment: Forgot to say, there's an alternative to send one message at a time rather than in batches. And remember to set the `ack` producer setting to >0 if you don't want to lose data.